# Set indentation of choice in exam documentclass

Tags: spacing, lists, indentation, exam

I want to create an multiple choices question with this indenting format

```
1. ########
   A. ###
   B. ###
   C. ###
2. ########
   ########
   A. ###
   B. ###
   C. ###
```

The choices have same indentation as the question text.

But, using the default `exam` documentclass, I get this format

```
1. ########
     A. ###
     B. ###
     C. ###
2. ########
   ########
     A. ###
     B. ###
     C. ###
```

Hence, I try to set the `\leftmargin` to `0pt` inside the `choices` environment to get what I want.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
  \question
  How old are you?
  \begin{choices}
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}
    \choice 14
    \choice 17
    \choice 19
    \choice 20
    \choice 23
  \end{choices}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

But, It get nowhere.

So, What is the right way to set indentation of `choice` in `exam` documentclass?

Answer (score 11):

Following Section 4.10 of the [`exam`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/exam) documentation, I believe you are looking for `choiceshook`, which can be used as follows, for example

```
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{30pt}%
}
\renewcommand{\choiceshook}{%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{50pt}%
}
```

Here is a complete MWE- I loaded the [`geometry`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/geometry) package with `showframe=true` just for demonstration.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: true}
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{30pt}%
}
\renewcommand{\choiceshook}{%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{50pt}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    \question
    How old are you?
    \begin{choices}
        \choice 14
        \choice 17
        \choice 19
        \choice 20
        \choice 23
    \end{choices}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

For reference, here's a quote from the `exam` documentation

> The exam document class defines these as follows:

```
\newcommand{\questionshook}{} 
\newcommand{\partshook}{}
\newcommand{\subpartshook}{} 
\newcommand{\subsubpartshook}{}
\newcommand{\choiceshook}{} 
\newcommand{\checkboxeshook}{}
```

> Thus, the default is that these commands have no effect, but you can change any of them with a \renewcommand command.

Comment: changing `\setlength{\leftmargin}{50pt}%` to `\settowidth{\leftmargin}{W.\hskip\labelsep\hskip 0em}` gives the desired result of indenting that I want. Though I'm pretty confused with the second argument of the `\settowidth` above.

Comment: I also wasn't able to get the solution here to work, but did get the one in your comment @MasAdit to work. I have no clue why though

Answer (score 5):

Try this and see

```
\uplevel{
\begin{choices}
    \choice 
    \choice 
    \choice 
    \choice 
\end{choices}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! To add syntax highlighting in a post, you can select the code and click the button marked `{}` above the text field.

Comment: Please add a document around your solution and provide a screen shot, in order to make this a real answer

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'm not sure a screenshot is always required, but I agree that some explanation  should be given.

Comment: @JosephWright: If I would be the OP (although the question is 'old') I would prefer a screen shot as a quick check if this provided solution fulfills the request. That's why I asked about the screen shot.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer 'Prefer' certainly: I was trying to say that one is not 'required' for an answer to be valid

Comment: @JosephWright: Agreed... there might be answers, where screen shots are not required or even possible.

Answer (score -1):

1. find your "exam.cls" on your latex folder.
2. open it,

change        `\settowidth{\leftmargin}{W.\hskip\labelsep\hskip 2.5em}%`
to        `\settowidth{\leftmargin}{W.\hskip\labelsep\hskip 0em}%`

3. save.

Comment: It's not a good idea to change the original class (.cls). You can add the necessary code in your own document.