# LaTeX Exam package: Align choices with oneparchoices

Tags: indentation, exam

I'm a fairly new LaTeX user, so please excuse me if this is a simple newbie question.

I am using the `exam` package to create, well, an exam. I use both the `\choices` and `\oneparchoices` environments and I would like them to be aligned instead of the choices ones being far more indented. This MWE should illustrate my point:

```
\documentclass{exam}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

   \question
    Question 1

   \begin{oneparchoices}
       \correctchoice Answer 1
       \choice Answer 2
       \choice Answer 3
   \end{oneparchoices}

   \question
   Question 2

   \begin{choices}
    \correctchoice Answer 1
    \choice Answer 2
    \choice Answer 3
   \end{choices}

   \end{questions}

 \end{document}
```

[image: This is what I get.]

I'm sure the more experienced users can solve this easily, but I'm stuck.

Comment: did you try the `\noindent` command after `\begin{choice}`?

Comment: @Yorgos: As `choices` is a list environment `\noindent` will not work. The indention is  done using `\leftmargin` not `\indent`.

Comment: @Yorgos. Yes, I tried that. Should have mentioned it.

Comment: I think this answer is much better than the currently selected one for this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108513/69346

Comment: Thanks, @ThoAppelsin! That works even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a look at the source code of the `exam` class shows me that the left margin (realized as `\leftmargin` in LaTeX) is set by `choices` using a hard coded line `\settowidth{\leftmargin}{W.\hskip\labelsep\hskip 2.5em}%`, i.e. it is set to the width of `W.` + labelsep + 2.5em (em is relative to your font size).

I don't see an easy way to change that as there is no setting for this provided. You only could copy the definition of `choices` from `exam.cls` into your document, between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, and change the above line to `\setlength{\leftmargin}{<your prefered length>}`. I would recommend here 15pt which is the normal `\parindent`. Your can't apparently not use `\parindent` directly as the list environment in `choices` seems to redefine it.
You also need to change `\newcommand` to `\renewcommand` of course.

```
\documentclass{exam}

\makeatletter
% from exam.cls, line 4107:
\renewenvironment{choices}%
  {\list{\choicelabel}%
     {\usecounter{choice}\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}%
       \setlength{\leftmargin}{15pt}%
       \def\choice{%
         \if@correctchoice
           \color@endgroup
           \endgroup
         \fi
         \item
         \do@choice@pageinfo
       } % choice
       \def\CorrectChoice{%
         \if@correctchoice
           \color@endgroup
           \endgroup
         \fi
         \ifprintanswers
           \ifhmode \unskip\unskip\unvbox\voidb@x \fi
           \begingroup \color@begingroup \@correctchoicetrue
           \CorrectChoice@Emphasis
         \fi
         \item
         \do@choice@pageinfo
       } % CorrectChoice
       \let\correctchoice\CorrectChoice
       \labelwidth\leftmargin\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
       \topsep=0pt
       \partopsep=0pt
       \choiceshook
     }%
  }%
  {\if@correctchoice \color@endgroup \endgroup \fi \endlist}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

   \question
    Question 1

   \begin{oneparchoices}
       \correctchoice Answer 1
       \choice Answer 2
       \choice Answer 3
   \end{oneparchoices}

   \question
   Question 2

   \begin{choices}
    \correctchoice Answer 1
    \choice Answer 2
    \choice Answer 3
   \end{choices}

   \end{questions}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is well beyond my current knowledge of LaTeX. But with the code you provided I got it to work. :)

Comment: How can I write options as (A),(B),.. instead of A.  , B. ,..?